# Code to find the root of a summation equation with various inputs

Tags: matlab, function

The Most Probable Number (MPN) function is an approach to estimate a population size or concentration (`x`) based upon the number (`n`) and size (`v`) of samples with that contain least one individual (`p`). Typical inputs may be:

```
n = 10  % total number of sample replicates
p = 8   % number of replicates with >=1 individual
v = 0.1 % Sample quantity (unit not specified)
```

If the inputs are scalar, then the solution can be obtained by solving the equation or by finding the zero root using the built-in Matlab function `fzero`:

```
f = @(x) v*n - (v*p)/(1-exp(-v*x)) % The basic MPN equation
solve_range = [1e-3,1e3];          % Range of iteration values
mpn = fzero(f, solve_range)
```

which returns `1.6094`. The solver is useful as there are typically multiple inputs (e.g., `p` is [8, 9, 7 .. i]) and, for this case, the value must be solved satisfying all of these inputs:

```
f = @(x)... 
v(1)*n(1)     - (v(1)*p(1))/(1-exp(-v(1)*x)) + ...
v(2)*n(2)     - (v(2)*p(2))/(1-exp(-v(2)*x)) + ...
...
v(end)*n(end) - (v(end)*p(end))/(1-exp(-v(end)*x))
```

Typically, the length of the array is 3 or 5, and it is almost always <10, so writing out a long function with the variables and indices is not unreasonable.

However, I am trying to expand the function to handle arrays of lengths >>100, and the function that is passed to `fzero` must be flexible to handle an unknown input length.

I have been searching for a simple way to do this. With no luck as of yet, I've made an inelegant workaround that writes a string based upon the number of inputs (replacing the variable indices using `regexprep`), and then I converted the string to a function using the built-in feature `inline`.

**I am hoping that someone knows a clever way to make a function that can be flexible to accept *variable* and *large* input lengths.** I've looked in to recursion and worked using nested anonymous functions, but I was not able to find the solution.

n.b: I am using an earlier version of MatLab (v7, R2011b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to [vectorize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) your objective function. From what I understand, the `n`, `p`, and/or `v` parameters can be vectors (if they are non-scalar, I'm assuming they have the same dimensions). You can vectorize your function with [element-wise operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) and [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html):

```
n = ...
p = ...
v = ...
f =  @(x)sum(v.*n-v.*p./(1-exp(-v.*x)));
...
```

If your goal to find multiple roots (using different initial guesses for `solve_range`) or to find roots of different equations (instances of `n`, `p`, and `v`), then you'll need to wrap your [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) call in a `for` loop.